# R list/dataframes to JSON array of objects

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to create a JSON array of objects using jsonlite in R.
The goal is a JSON like this:

```
{
  "top":[
    {
      "master1": {
      "item1": "value1"
      }
    },
    {
      "master2": {
      "item2": "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried list of lists and dataframes with list column but can't get the desired output.
Apart from that, converting the above with fromJSON/toJSON results in a different format:

```
library(jsonlite)
txt <- '{
  "top":[
    {
      "master1": {
      "item1": "value1"
      }
    },
    {
      "master2": {
      "item2": "value2"
      }
    }]
}'

toJSON(fromJSON(txt), pretty = T)

# Output
{
  "top": [
    {
      "master1": {
        "item1": "value1"
      },
      "master2": {}
    },
    {
      "master1": {},
      "master2": {
        "item2": "value2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to set a parameter for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `fromJSON` call converts your input to a data frame, and therefore adds `NA` values, which result in the empty entries in your output JSON:

```
$top
   item1  item2
1 value1   <NA>
2   <NA> value2
```

You need to add `simplifyDataFrame = FALSE` to the `fromJSON` call to prevent it from creating a data frame.

```
toJSON(fromJSON(txt, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE), pretty = T)
```

gives

```
{
  "top": [
    {
      "master1": {
        "item1": ["value1"]
      }
    },
    {
      "master2": {
        "item2": ["value2"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```